# Difference between gradle build vs gradle war

Tags: java, gradle

What is the difference between

```
apply plugin: "war"
```

and then executing:

```
./gradlew build
```

or

```
./gradlew war
```

?

Comment: Does my answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 6):

It can easily explainable if you look at the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/userguide/userguide.html#gsc.tab=0) and this two diagrams in particular:

**Java plugin tasks**:

[image]

**War plugin tasks**:

[image]

`build` is just a lifecycle task that is added with [`LifecycleBasePlugin`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/javadoc/org/gradle/language/base/plugins/LifecycleBasePlugin.html). As you can see it depends on `assemble` which in turn depends on `war`. So both `build` and `war` will prepare the final artifact.

Comment: fantastic explanation

Comment: This answer doesn't explicitly explain the consequences.  When would you use one over the other for example?  It appears "war" doesn't execute tests, so perhaps "war" is a shortcut for "build -x test", only applicable to web projects of course.